# How I do I know which Controller needs to be created in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Being newbie in ASP.Net MVC 4, I am kind of lost. Following a path to create a model for the application (report generating website) I have created a simple View page which has 5 drop down lists and needs to populate data directly from the database(existing DB). I have created the ViewModel with few sample entity classes (e.g. ReportContext, SearchModel, ReportModel etc.). Now the turn is to create controller (or should I have done this earlier?). I am not sure what exactly needs to be created. Suppose I am doing a search page. I need (i) parameter selection and then (ii) view results. These are the two basic initial actions will be executed. What could be the way of creating controller for them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Controller would receive search params and fetch data from DB, building view model. That would be then passed to view for rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general what the controller does is create a connection between your model (data) and your view. So you want to create functions that fill up your drop down lists with data from your model and when a button is clicked (search for example) the controller will contain an even handler function which will take data from your view state and use them to query the database and bring back the result.

That of course is the overview only cause I don't have enough info on your exact application.

You should check out the official tutorials of MVC4 - It's a great way to start and understand how the MVC model works.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: I did follow the getting started tutorial, however there it started with creating controller first. Hence it was bit confusing with all "Code First" or "DB first" terms. But your answer makes more sense and gives me the idea to start. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Np glad I helped! I recently started playing with MVC4 myself and that tutorial helped a lot. There's also Darin Dimitrov (in SO) who is an expert on the subject and helped quite a bit with his answers.